# Лог доступа gunicorn + nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, wsgi

Запускаю свое Flask приложение с помощью gunicorn, использую при этом nginx.
Для связи я использую unix-сокет.
Ниже строка запуска приложения:

```
gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myapp.sock -m 007 --access-logfile /var/log/myapp/access.log app:app
```

Далее часть конфига nginx.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name hostname;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/socket/myapp.sock;
        }

    }
```

В итоге, в логе доступа access.log у меня заменяется на дефолтные

```
 - - [27/Jun/2019:11:03:56 +0300] "POST /ask HTTP/1.0" 200 108 "http://hostname.host" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
```

По ней я не могу отследить с какого адреса происходит обращение к приложению, а также другие данные.

Я нашел, что похожая проблема обсуждается [тут](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/797), однако, так и не понял, какие изменения мне надо добавить для корректной работы.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Читайте логи nginx вместо логов gunicorn (а в gunicorn логи вообще отключите)

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю. Но все же почему лог gunicorn не формируется корректно?

Comment: Потому что для unix-сокетов не существует понятия IP-адрес и взять его неоткуда. Его nginx, конечно, передаст в HTTP-заголовках (X-Real-IP), только вот gunicorn совершенно не обязан доверять каким-то там левым HTTP-заголовкам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gunicorn запускается как внутренний сервер, он работает на локалхосте,
nginx - слушает внешние адреса и проксирует их на локалхост.
Тоесть когда вы делаете запрос к серверу: nginx принимает его, делает 100% такой же запрос на gunicorn но уже через локальный адрес.

Поэтому вы и получаете такие логи, nginx - пишет внешние адреса, gunicorn - пишет локалхост так как на нем же и запущен.
Лично я обычно использую только логи nginx или apache, внутренние логи читать особого смысла нету.